# dalvik Java How to call super class method using reflect?

Tags: java, android, reflection

I my case:
I want to override a hide method in `TextView` by extends `TextView`, and make call to its super method.

```
public class MyTextView extends TextView {
    protected void makeNewLayout(int wantWidth, int hintWidth,
                                 BoringLayout.Metrics boring,
                                 BoringLayout.Metrics hintBoring,
                                 int ellipsisWidth, boolean bringIntoView) {
        // omit try catch for simple
        Method method = Class.forName("android.widget.TextView").getDeclaredMethod("makeNewLayout", int.class, int.class, BoringLayout.Metrics.class, BoringLayout.Metrics.class, int.class, boolean.class);
        method.setAccessible(true);
        method.invoke(this, wantWidth, hintWidth, boring, hintBoring, ellipsisWidth, bringIntoView);
    }
}
```

The problem is my self define `makeNewLayout` is called and the method.invoke is executed, but the method invoke is **`MyTextView::makeNewLayout`** not **`TextView::makeNewLayout`**, it a dead recursive call.

How can I acheive it?

PS: makeNewLayout is a hide function, so I cannot call it directly by `super.makeNewLayout(...)`

Looks like it's not possible for java/android to do this kind of work easily. java is too safe to hack around.

Comment: Don't override. Rename your makeNewLayout to something else.

Comment: @laune yeah, that will work, but what I want is to hook the time TextView called makeNewLayout, and do some work based on that.

Comment: if it is hidden then devs had a good reason of doing this, what do you need it for?

Comment: @pskink because there are some bugs in `TextView` like: imagespan or other custom spans conflict with ellipsize setting, and also the `EditText` with multiple imagespans has some strange behaviors(the layout truncate newline result changes when it should not changed), looks like it is caused by DynamicLayout reflow(I'm not very sure).

Comment: @pskink like this bug, textview goes to multiline, or textview's widthmode is WRAP_CONTENT, it will still be a problem. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28892115/android-imagespan-image-is-cut-error-in-singleline-textview   I think the best solution is to implement own TextView not extend android's `TextView`, but it will need more effort.

Comment: sorry but what you want cannot be done, if it has bugs you can open the bug report in the Issue Tracker and wait till it is fixed...

Answer (score 1):

There's a solution below android 8.0 if you can accept packaging some *.so library. There's a family of calling non-virtual methods in JNI interface (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/jni/spec/functions.html#CallNonvirtual_type_Method_routines)
Using it like this:

Declaring in java:

```
public native void callNonvirtualVoidMethodHelper(Object obj, String classNameOfMethod, String methodName, String methodSignature);
```

Implementation in cpp:

```
extern "C"
JNIEXPORT
void JNICALL
Java_yourpackage_yourclass_callNonvirtualVoidMethodHelper(
    JNIEnv *env,
    jobject /* this */,
    jobject obj,
    jstring classNameOfMethod,
    jstring methodName,
    jstring methodSignature) {
    const char *classNameStr = env->GetStringUTFChars(classNameOfMethod, JNI_FALSE);
    const char *methodNameStr = env->GetStringUTFChars(methodName, JNI_FALSE);
    const char *methodSignatureStr = env->GetStringUTFChars(methodSignature, JNI_FALSE);
    jclass classOfMethod = env->FindClass(classNameStr);
    jmethodID method = env->GetMethodID(classOfMethod, methodNameStr, methodSignatureStr);
    env->CallNonvirtualVoidMethod(obj, classOfMethod, method);
}
```

Using it in java:

```
callNonvirtualVoidMethodHelper(new SubClass(),
        "some/package/SuperClass", // specify the class of non-virtual method
        "foo",
        "()V"); // method signature
```

Or using MethodHandle when running above android 8.0 (Reference: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15674467/2300252).